# BigQuery: Extract values of selected keys from an array of json objects

Tags: arrays, json, select, google-bigquery

I have a json in bigQuery

```
{
  "actors": {
    "stooges": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Larry"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Curly"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Moe"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I extract each of the `.name`s in bigQuery.

```
["Larry", "Curly", "Moe"]
```

Here are some handy bigQuery compatible statements(based on above json).

```
-- Declaring a bigQuery variable 
DECLARE json_data JSON DEFAULT (SELECT PARSE_JSON('{ "actors": {"stooges": [{"id": 1,"name": "Larry"},{"id": 2,"name": "Curly"},{"id": 3,"name": "Moe"}]}}'));

-- Select statement. But this is no good for my use case since I don't want to specify element index ([0]) as the array size is dynamic
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, '$.actors.stooges[0].name');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try and consider below approach using `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY()` then unnest it and then use `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR()` to extract the values. You may refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array) for more details in BigQuery JSON functions.

```sql
select ARRAY(
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_array, '$.name') from UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_data,"$.actors.stooges"))json_array
)extracted_names
```

**Output:**
[image]